# Group wise maximum value column in MySQL : Self join

Tags: mysql, group-by

MySQL Table with name, email, auction_id and bid.  I am trying to get the MAX bid and the email address from the max bid row while using a GROUP by auction_id.

I can get the MAX bid amount returned but the email address that is returned is not for the MAX bid.

```
SELECT email, MAX(bid) FROM `kisd_wdm_bidders` GROUP BY auction_id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do `SELF JOIN`(Not precisely)

```
SELECT T1.auction_id,T1.email,T1.bid
    FROM kisd_wdm_bidders AS T1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT auction_id, MAX(bid) AS max_bid
        FROM kisd_wdm_bidders
        GROUP BY auction_id
    ) AS T2
    ON T1.auction_id  = T2.auction_id AND T2.max_bid =T1.bid
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Generally don't use a columns in `SELECT` that is not used in the aggregation. Have a look [here](http://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). Also try this:

```
SELECT aa.email, _aa.max_bid
FROM kisd_wdm_bidders AS aa
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT auction_id, MAX(bid) AS max_bid
    FROM kisd_wdm_bidders
    GROUP BY auction_id
) AS _aa
ON aa.auction_id = _aa.auction_id AND aa.bid = _aa.max_bid;
```

Comment: You have to add at the end `AND aa.bid  = _aa.max_bid` or the response will contain any `email` for a certain `action_id`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tend to forgot it in queries like this.